# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: getLonAndLat is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, function, getter-setter

Running JavaScript on VS-Code. I have the following code as my main file:

```
d3.json("./data/trueData.json").then(function (data) {
  let regionNameVar2;
  let regionLatVar2;
  let regionLngVar2;

  let regionCordinates2 = [];
  let queryKey = [];
  let metroArray = [];


    for (let x in data) {

      // attempt to grab the values using square bracket notation
      regionNameVar2 = data[x]["RegionName"];
     // regionLatVar2 = data[x]["RegionLat"];
     // regionLngVar2 = data[x]["RegionLng"];

      // outputs both region latitude and region longitude to make region cordinates
      regionCordinates2 = [regionLatVar2, regionLngVar2];

     // queryKey = [regionLatVar2, regionLngVar2];
     
      for (let y in data[x]) {
      console.log(y)

    }

 

  // tests variable output
     console.log(`++++++++`);
    // console.log(`${x}'s region name is ` + regionNameVar2);
    // console.log(`${x}'s cordnaties are ` + regionCordinates2);
     //console.log(`test of queryKey: + ${queryKey}`);


  }// "for (let x in data)'s" end bracket


    //activates test call function
    testCall();


    //activates setLonandLat function
     setLonAndLat();

    getLonAndLat();

    
   //test calls the getLonAndLat function to see if its working
   function testCall(getLonAndLat)
    {
       getLonAndLat(metroArray);
       console.log(metroArray);
    }
 
 
    //sets the latitude and longitude to a array
    function setLonAndLat(queryKey)
    {   
      for (let x in data)
       {
          regionLatVar2 = data[x]["RegionLat"];
          regionLngVar2 = data[x]["RegionLng"];
          queryKey = [regionLatVar2, regionLngVar2];
          //metroArray = queryKey;
        }
        console.log(`function setAndLat is active!}`);
       return queryKey;
    }


    //gets the longitude and latitude from the array
    function getLonAndLat(setLonAndLat)
    {
    setLonAndLat();
    metroArray = queryKey;
    console.log("Function getLonAndLat is active!");
    return metroArray;
    }
 
 }

)
```

Here is the JSON file:

```
{
    "Malden": {
        "RegionID": "12519",
        "SizeRank": "26884",
        "RegionName": "Malden",
        "RegionType": "city",
        "StateName": "NY",
        "State": "NY",
        "Metro": "Kingston, NY",
        "CountyName": "Ulster County",
        "CountyLat": "41.6370",
        "CountyLng": "-74.2633",
        "RegionLat": "42.0951",
        "RegionLng": "-73.9351",
        "2013-01-31": "186572.56047947207",
        "2013-02-28": "186467.29556400285",
        "2013-03-31": "186074.57716018287",
        "2013-04-30": "185635.1640155002"
      },
 "Wallkill": {
        "RegionID": "27749",
        "SizeRank": "3782",
        "RegionName": "Wallkill",
        "RegionType": "city",
        "StateName": "NY",
        "State": "NY",
        "Metro": "Kingston, NY",
        "CountyName": "Ulster County",
        "CountyLat": "41.6370",
        "CountyLng": "-74.2633",
        "RegionLat": "41.6092",
        "RegionLng": "-74.1648",
        "2013-01-31": "218057.87372541023",
        "2013-02-28": "218617.5003372829",
        "2013-03-31": "218982.9075352271",
        "2013-04-30": "220261.8385379552",
        "2013-05-31": "221329.43855296331",
        "2013-06-30": "222295.59874303863",
        "2013-07-31": "222892.1280908118",
        "2013-08-31": "223333.7489902942",
        "2013-09-30": "222871.1465983206",
        "2013-10-31": "221638.47638018383",
        "2013-11-30": "219516.0006267724",
        "2013-12-31": "218758.72737439172"
       },
    "Pine Hill": {
        "RegionID": "26504",
        "SizeRank": "27622",
        "RegionName": "Pine Hill",
        "RegionType": "city",
        "StateName": "NY",
        "State": "NY",
        "Metro": "Kingston, NY",
        "CountyName": "Ulster County",
        "CountyLat": "41.6370",
        "CountyLng": "-74.2633",
        "RegionLat": "42.1257",
        "RegionLng": "-74.4672",
        "2013-01-31": "",
        "2013-02-28": "",
        "2013-03-31": "",
        "2013-04-30": "",
        "2013-05-31": "",
        "2013-06-30": "",
        "2013-07-31": "",
        "2013-08-31": "",
        "2013-09-30": "",
        "2013-10-31": "",
        "2013-11-30": "",
        "2013-12-31": "",
        "2014-01-31": "",
        "2014-02-28": "",
        "2014-03-31": "",
        "2014-04-30": "",
        "2014-05-31": "",
        "2014-06-30": "",
        "2014-07-31": "",
        "2014-08-31": "",
        "2014-09-30": "",
        "2014-10-31": "",
        "2014-11-30": "",
        "2014-12-31": "",
        "2015-01-31": "",
        "2015-02-28": "",
        "2015-03-31": "",
        "2015-04-30": "",
        "2015-05-31": "",
        "2015-06-30": "",
        "2015-07-31": "",
        "2015-08-31": "",
        "2015-09-30": "",
        "2015-10-31": ""
}
}
```

I tried running the code after commenting out the `setLonAndLat();` line that's in the getLngAndLat function, but that resulted in the setLonAndLat argument being grayed out. And the error message remained the same. Its obviously a function, so I'm confused as to how 'getLngAndLat' is not a function to the console.

Any explanation as to how its not registering as a function would be much apricated. Solution to fix this is optional.

Comment: The parameter in `function testCall(getLonAndLat)` shadows the `getLonAndLat` function. And you call `testCall();` without passing an argument, therefore the value for the *parameter* called `getLonAndLat` is `undefined`.